# How can you access a registered class of a Blender add-on from another Blender add-on?

Tags: python, add-on

TL;DR: I would like to use a subclass of PropertyGroup defined in one add-on as the type of a PointerProperty property of another add-on.

I have two addons, Foo and Bar like this:

**Foo**

```py
# foo.py
# ...

class FooProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):   
    foo_value: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Guess what", default=1)

# ...


class SOMEONE_OT_FooMaker(Operator):    
    bl_idname = "someone.foomaker"
    # ...

# ...
```

```py
# __init__.py
# ...

def register()
    # ...
    bpy.utils.register_class(foo.FooProps)
    bpy.utils.register_class(foo.SOMEONE_OT_FooMaker)
    # ...
# ...
```

**Bar**

```py
# bar.py

class BarPrefs(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    # ...
    foo_stuff: bpy.types.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.FooProps)
    # ...
```

Here I would like to access the registered class `FooProps` of add-on Foo from the another add-on Bar. As `FooProps` is registered with Blender, I would expect it to appear in `bpy.types`, however it doesn't appear there. While debugging I can list what `bpy.types` has to offer, and while I can find `bpy.types.SOMEONE_OT_FooMaker`, there is no `bpy.types.FooProps`.

What may I overlook? Shall I follow the wrong path, can you nudge me to the right one?

[Full (non-)working example here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wjLDNXUNZ5LUl1V-d1xXhBPJcJfyQ15R/view?usp=drive_link)